# Are there any free Linux terminals in Windows 10 to deploy kivy application

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, kivy

I have to deploy a kivy application to android and I know how to do that, but I don't want to spend money on simply deploying a app to android. So are there any free linux terminals for windows 10.

Here is my kivy program code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label("Hello World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

My python version is 3.7.0

Comment: Can't you just copy the `apk` file to your device using a USB cable? Or memory stick? Or via a webserver? Why is a terminal required?

Comment: Thank you everyone I will try whatever answers you all posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use [wsl2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) (windows sub system for Linux)

But make sure to build on the `/home/` directory not in `/mnt/`

[look a this to instal WSl2](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=AfVH54edAHU)

[then this. To get a easier to use gui](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dgdOILL1184)

on the wsl gui make a folder on the desktop
run:

```
sudo apt install python3
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

and follow  this tut :
https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
follow  ubuntu

(run the commands one at the time) and dont forget to edit the .bashrc file

```
code ~/.bashrc
```

or go in the gui then explorer in  /home  view show hiden files and edit it

and finally:

```
buildozer init
```

dont edit to many things in buildozer.spec just names, domain, requierement ...

don’t  edit the ndk sdk version let the rest as default

```
buildozer android debug
```

wait ...

and your done
this is the only way I succeeded building the apk

Hope this helped

**ERRORS:**

If you get the error `c compiler cannot make executables`  that mean you are in the `/mnt/` directory (were windows files are)